# What is this plant found on a lake shore in Maine?

Tags: identification

This plant has a purplish stem with fine hairs. Also the leaves sprout from stem opposite. However, it is two leaves at a time and rotates on way up?

It's growing on sandy beach on a lake in Maine.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible for you to take a photo where the focus (sharp area) is on the  plant? As it stands the focus is on the blue object behind the plant making it unnecessary difficult to the details. Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2):

Despite the pic being out of focus, it looks awfully like Eupatorium perfoliatum, specially if the stem is hairy, but that plant is usually green, sometimes with brownish tinges to the leaves, and grows in damp areas, so it would be unusual to find it growing in beach sand. The second picture on the right lower down in the link below shows it reasonably clearly

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eupatorium_perfoliatum

Comment: wow...i think you nailed it! I'll still try to get another pic, but awesome, really does look like it.